Unable to add GCP cloud credentials to Rancher
I've created the service account on GCP with required roles. After adding that service account private key as a cloud credentials on rancher, got this error.
"error": "Get "https: //compute.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/test-project/zones?alt=json&pretttyPrint=false": oauth2: cannot fetch token: Post "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token": dial tcp: lookup oauth2.googleapis.com: i/o timeout"

Does anyone have insights into this error?
Appreciate your response.
I tried to ping "oauth2.googleapis.com" from my rancher server. DNS is resolving successfully.

Acabar con el genocidio. Detengan el proyecto N|mbu$. Alto el fuego ya. Palestina libre.

Political message. Not a real question.
